# Move an element from an array

Tags: c#

How can I move an element from an index, for example to the front. Let's say this example : moving the second index to the front, and the rest of the elements remain the same. As I am working with algorithms I can't implement things like lists that I found most efficient I guess.

Example : 1 2 3 4

Output : 3 1 2 4

I assigned the value from the index to a temporary variable so far. But I do not know how to shift the elements, I'm guessing implementing somehow a for loop.

Comment: It might help you to draw the steps on a piece of paper and see if you can translate that into code. `1 2 3 4` `1 2 [] 4 : 3` `1 [] 2 4 : 3` etc.

Comment: SO wont write code for you, try something and when you get stuck post you code along with the problem you are having

Comment: The ol' switcheroo. `int x = arr[0]; arr[0] = arr[2]; arr[2] = x`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change how you iterate based on whether your desired index is before or after the elements original index and handle those cases individually.

```
public static void MoveToIndex(int[] array, int from, int to)
{
    if (array.Length < 2) return;
    if (from == to) return;
    if (from < 0 || array.Length <= from) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(from));
    if (to < 0 || array.Length <= to) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(to));

    var startIndex = Math.Min(from, to);
    var endIndex = Math.Max(from, to);
    var swappedValue = array[startIndex];
    if (to < from)
    {
        array[startIndex] = array[endIndex];
    }
    for (var i = startIndex + 1; i <= endIndex; i++)
    {
        var current = array[i];
        if (to < from)
        {
            array[i] = swappedValue;
            swappedValue = current;
        }
        else
        {
            array[i - 1] = i == endIndex ? swappedValue : current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice - you did someone's homework for them, without them showing any effort.

Comment: @Kevin Took me like 10 minutes to code up. I'm not sweating it and sometimes you just get stuck and need a solid example to understand where you went wrong.

Comment: Not really my point. Homework is supposed to be a learning exercise, and SO is not meant to be a coding service. In cases like this maybe right some pseduo-code to get them started on the right track.